# Increment a counter every time the page refreshes

Tags: javascript

How to increment and save counter value on page refresh ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<script>

var count;
var index;
function myFunction() {
count++;
alert("after count++"+count);
localStorage.setItem("incCount",count);


alert("index here :"+index);
if(index==1){
var s=localStorage.getItem("incCount");
alert("s is"+s)
}
index++;

localStorage.setItem("incIndex",index);
var g=localStorage.getItem("incIndex");
alert("g is "+g)


alert("index after index++"+index)

  alert("Page is loaded");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to increase the count variable value by 1 , every time I refresh the page .But , its not working as per my expectation , what should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the count from `local storage`, convert it to a number using the `Number` function, and increment it while storing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      let count = Number(localStorage.getItem('count')) || 0;
      alert(`count ${count}`);
      localStorage.setItem('count', count + 1);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you're doing on page load is increment an undefined variable `count` to 1, then storing that in localStorage `incCount`.  So that will always be 1.

Instead, you need to read the existing value first and increment that. (Here I use `|| 0` to handle the case where no localStorage yet exists):

```
var count;
function myFunction() { // you should probably use a better name here
  const previousCount = Number(localStorage.getItem("incCount")) || 0;
  count = previousCount + 1;
  localStorage.setItem("incCount",count);
}
```

I've omitted the `index` variable here because I'm really not clear what you were trying to do with that, or if it's related to the given question; to just keep an incrementing count you only need the one variable.

Answer (score 0):

To increment a count on page refresh all you have to do is to first check whether there is already a value for that `incCount` key or not.

If it is not then you have to create a localStorage `key-value` and if it is already there then you just have to set incremented value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <script>
    let count = 0; // change

    function myFunction() {
      const valueInLS = localStorage.getItem("incCount");
      alert(valueInLS);
      if (valueInLS) count = valueInLS;
      localStorage.setItem("incCount", ++count);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```